# Prevent people who commited in a PR from merging/reviewing

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I have a, what I thought, fairly simple use case for Bitbucket:

An open pull request should only be allowed to be merged/reviewed by a person that did not create a commit in that pull request. Of course, this does not include "external" commits like merge commits.

I didn't find a single Bitbucket extension that provides this functionality.

Do I have to write my own web hook? If so, any chance to let me know how to get started there? I can easily write a small backend to handle/create requests, but when I evaluate "this person is not allowed to merge that PR", how do I let Bitbucket know that this user can't click on "merge" in the web UI of his browser?

Comment: [Use branch permissions](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-branch-permissions/).

Comment: If 3 different people collaborated and have commits in a PR, you don't want any of them to review the entire PR? Why not?